# Relacionamento 1 para 1 com Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Tenho 2 entidades: `Equipamento` e `Databook`. Um `Equipamento` só pode ter um `Databook` e um `Databook` so é para um `Equipamento`. Como posso fazer este relacionamento com Entity Framework?

Segue as Classes:

```
public class Equipamento
{
    public int EquipamentoID { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public Databook databook { get; set; }
}

public class Databook
{
    public int DatabookID { get; set; }

    public string Indentificacao { get; set; }   
    public Equipamento equipamento { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um mapeamento one to one se faz através do relacionamento onde a chave de um também é chave do outro. Assim teremos o campo chave na classe `Todo` sendo a chave da classe `parte`.

```
public class Todo{
    public virtual Parte ObjParte { get; set; }
}

public class Parte{
    [Key]
    public int TodoID { get; set; }
    public virtual Todo ObjTodo { get; set; }
}
```

Na classe `Contexto` podemos fazer esse mapeamento também com ***Fluent Api***:

```
public class Contexto {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parte>()
            .HasKey(x => x.TodoID)
            .HasRequired(x => x.ObjTodo)
            .WithRequiredDependent(p => p.ObjParte);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como já dito na resposta do @TiagoSilva, essa abordagem funciona, porém fere a normalização e as convenções do Entity Framework.

Answer (score 5):

Geralmente, o relacionamento é feito atráves da informação de Chaves Estrangeiras (as *Foreign Keys*).

Por anotação com atributos, ficaria dessa forma em `Equipamento`:

```cs
public class Equipamento
{
    [Key]
    public int EquipamentoID { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }

    // Conforme comentário do AP, essa propriedade não pode existir, ou o EF se perde.
    //public virtual Databook databook { get; set; } 
}
```

Note o uso de `virtual`. É recomendado principalmente quando se usa o *Entity Framework* com configuração de uso de classes proxies. Aqui, a propriedade do tipo `Databook` se torna apenas uma propriedade de navegação.

Uma propriedade de navegação apenas sinaliza ao Entitu Framework que um registro relacionado pode ser encontrado na entidade indicada. Neste caso, estamos indicando que um `Equipamento` pode (ou não) ter um `Databook`.

E dessa forma em `Databook`:

```cs
public class Databook
{       
    [Key]
    public int DatabookID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("equipamento")]
    public int EquipamentoID { get; set; }   
    public virtual Equipamento equipamento { get; set; }

    // ou assim:
    // sendo esse caso o necessário para quando se trata de entidades 
    // com chaves compostas.
    //
    //[Key]
    //public int EquipamentoID { get; set; }   
    //[ForeignKey("EequipamentoId")]
    //public virtual Equipamento equipamento { get; set; }

    public string Indentificacao { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: tenho que configurar alguma coisa no meu contexto?

Comment: @Janderson, para o contexto, é basicamente declarar as propriedades do tipo `DbSet<T>`.

Comment: Tiago, obrigado! Como ficaria nas views e nos controllers, pode me ajudar?

Comment: @Janderson, isso já é outra pergunta. Você até pode adicionar nessa outra pergunta o link para essa como referência, mas é outra pergunta.

Comment: Tiago, ja fiz outra pergunta de como ficaria nas views e nos controllers segue link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38014/relacionamento-1-para-1-asp-net-mvc-com-entity-framework

Comment: @TiagoSilva, está dando este erro: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Databook_equipamento_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Databook_equipamento_Source' in relationship 'Databook_equipamento'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'. O que faço?

Comment: @Janderson/Cigano, <<--- Isso funciona? Na verdade a propriedade de navegação `public virtual Databook databook { get; set; }` em `Equipamento` só é aceito se a chave estrangeira em `Databook` ligando à `Equipamento` fosse a *chave primária*. Assumo que isso eu não entendi perfeitamente.

Comment: @Janderson, comentei a propriedade que te falei, na resposta, para demonstrar o que eu disse nos comentários.

Comment: @TiagoSilva, dessa forma não sera relação 1 para N ?

Comment: @Janderson, não. `Equipamento` não tem ligação com outra classe, e `Databook` tem ligação com apenas um `Equipamento` (como representado pelas propriedades que compõem a FK, a `EquipamentoID` e `equipamento`).