# Relacionamento EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Sei que é algo básico, mas como faço um relacionamento entre Entidades usando o Entity Framework?

Tenho a tabela Concurso e a StatusConcursos. A tabela Concurso deve ter um status associado(Normal, Cancelado e etc).

Segue abaixo o código das classes:

```
[Table("Concursos")]
public class Concurso
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 5)]
    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "A data de cadastro deve ser informada.")]
    [Display(Name = "Data Cadastro")]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "A data de início deve ser informada.")]
    [Display(Name = "Data Início")]
    public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Data Fim")]
    public DateTime DataFim { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Observacao")]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "The {0} deve ter no maximo {1} letras.")]
    public string Observacao { get; set; }

    public int? StatusID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StatusID")]
    public virtual StatusConcursos StatusConcurso { get; set; }

}
```

---

```
public class StatusConcursos
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual Concurso Concurso { get; set; }

}
```

Da maneira como está ocorre erro quando tento criar uma nova migration. Segue mensagem de erro:

> `Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'WellPlayed.Models.StatusConcursos' and 'WellPlayed.Models.Concurso'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.`

Comment: Como `Concursos` se relaciona com `StatusConcursos`?

Comment: Na tabela Concursos na coluna StatusId deve ter o Id referente ao StatusConcursos.

Comment: O relacionamento é 1 para muitos onde um Concursos pode ter um StatusConcursos???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for **`1`** para **`muitos`** faça a modificação em `StatusConcursos` que possui uma lista de `Concurso`:

```
[Table("StatusConcursos")]
public class StatusConcursos
{
    public StatusConcursos()
    {
        Concursos = new HashSet<Concurso>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Concurso> Concursos { get; set; }

}
```

<sup>***Observação:*** A `Concurso` não precisa de nenhuma alteração.</sup>

**Leitura útil:**

- [Mapeamento com Entity Framework Code First (Fluent Api) – Parte 1](http://netcoders.com.br/blog/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-1/)
- [Mapeamento com Entity Framework Code First (Fluent Api) – Parte 2](http://netcoders.com.br/blog/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-2/)
- [Relacionamento 1 para 1 com Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37944/relacionamento-1-para-1-com-entity-framework)
- [Relacionamento Muitos Para Muitos Entity Framework 6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14829/relacionamento-muitos-para-muitos-entity-framework-6)
- [Entity Framework – Usando Fluent API para definir relacionamentos](http://imasters.com.br/apis/entity-framework-usando-fluent-api-para-definir-relacionamentos/?trace=1519021197)
- [EF.MVC.Mappings](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EF.MVC.Mappings)

Comment: Funcionou exatamente como eu queria.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, primeiramente vou mostra um pouco de como eu costumo fazer em meus projetos quando tenho a questão do `Status` em determinadas funcionalidades.

Para realizar o mapeamento em meus projetos, eu defino um histórico na entidade principal, que no seu caso é o `Concurso`. Ficando da seguinte forma

```
    [Table("Concursos")]
    public class Concurso
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Display(Name = "Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 5)]
        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "A data de cadastro deve ser informada.")]
        [Display(Name = "Data Cadastro")]
        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "A data de início deve ser informada.")]
        [Display(Name = "Data Início")]
        public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Data Fim")]
        public DateTime DataFim { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Observacao")]
        [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "The {0} deve ter no maximo {1} letras.")]
        public string Observacao { get; set; }
        //histórico de status para o concurso
        public ICollection<ConcursoHistorico> ConcursosHistoricos { get; set; }    
    }
```

A segunda parte, é definir a entidade `ConcursoHistorico`, ficando da seguinte forma

```
    [Table("ConcursosHistoricos")]
    public class ConcursoHistorico
    {
        public int ConcursoHistoricoId { get; set; }
        public ConcursoStatus Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get ;set; }
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        public int ConcursoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Concurso Concurso { get; set; }
    }
```

e também tenho um `Enum` com os possíveis status

```
public enum ConcursoStatus
    {
        Normal = 1,
        Cancelado = 2
    }
```

Nesse exemplo que lhe proponho, fica definido que o mapeamento é de 1 para muitos, sendo que um concurso vai ter sempre vários históricos. Sendo o último histórico inserido, o status atual do concurso, podendo você fazer algo do tipo para recuperar o status atual

```
            using (TesteContext context = new TesteContext())
            {
                var concurso = context.Concursos.Include(a => a.ConcursosHistoricos).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == 1);

                var status = concurso.ConcursosHistoricos.OrderBy(a => a.Data).Last();
            }
```

Veja nesse [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) várias exemplos de mapeamento

Comment: Pablo, muito interessante esse método, vou verificar se vai ser necessário usar esse modelo de histórico.